# Alterar a propriedade de um objeto QML pelo C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Estou tentando realizar a alteração de uma propriedade de um objeto *(Rectangle)* que foi instanciado no QML, porém não estou conseguindo realiza-lo pois o método **findChild** retorna ***null***.

Eu estou seguindo as seguintes documentações:

-[Integrating QML and C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)

-[Interacting with QML Objects from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)

### Main

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

  QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();

  QObject *rect = ctxt->findChild<QObject*>("rect");
  if (rect)
          rect->setProperty("color", "blue");
  return app.exec();
}
```

### QML

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    title: "Redi"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    visibility : "Maximized"
    Rectangle{
        y:100
        x:100
        width: 100
        height: 100
        objectName: "rect"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri uma solução, mas não consegui entender o porque o método **findChild** retorna ***null***. Ao realizar alguns testes percebi que o método **rootObjects** me retornava um objeto que possuía o mesmo **objectname** do formulário que possui o objeto que quero alterar a propriedade e deste modo que retorna a janela eu consegui realizar a alteração da propriedade e realizar a busca de outros objetos.

Basicamente o fonte ficou desta maneira.

### Main

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickItem>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject *rect = engine.rootObjects().first()->findChild<QObject *>("rect");//Alerado de rootContext para rootObjects
    if (rect)
        rect->setProperty("color", "blue");

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

### Resultado

**No modo design do Qt Creator**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Na aplicação**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]